# Multi Filterable Table with big Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, datatable

Im trying to setup a website that displays ~800.000 rows with 20 columns in a table that is sortable and filterable by checkboxes.

In Detail:

- ~800.000 rows @ 20 columns
- data comes from MySQL database
- table needs to be filterable
- table needs to be sortable:
  -> at top of each column are multiple checkboxes, for every possible result of the column one (some have 5 others 15, maybe checkboxes in a dropdown?!)
  -> data should be updated immediately or after button press
- table needs pagination or show a Maximum of 500 rows (user needs to filter than to find his requested data but saves work on pagination)

What are the best ways to design such project?
- Html / php  / js / existing tools or scripts

My Skills in all of them are low but im learning by doing at this project.

For clearance: the table holds data for a game. Heros and the equiment they can have and what stats they got with it, all possible combinations. And the user mostlx wants THE BEST for every caregory or THE BEST he can do with his stuff. ---> so i guess pagination is unimportant.

Comment: if you do decide to use angular(which you should), also incorporate [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), also do you want to filter in the frontend or backend? backend might make it a little easier given that you want pagination.

Comment: Im unsure about pagination, mostly the user is only interested in the top 100 of the filtered and sorted data, if i show 500 he has some more reference to look over. I guess i drop the pagination as it simplyfies everything.

Comment: Maybe i can combine this: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/selectbox/ with http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/

Comment: This can easily be done with angular filter and a table along with dynamic classes

Comment: You got some good ressource for that or i need to google several sites in hope of a good one.